# Specific case of non-greedy `grep`

Tags: regex, grep

I know there are many examples of a non-greedy regex with grep, but I'm having problems with my specific case.

My file contains lines similar to:

```
[X12345.Yabc.Z7989].[ALPHA/BRAVO].[CHARLIE.DELTA]
```

and I'm trying to parse out just the `X12345` part.
*That is, the part starting with `X` and up until the first period (`.`)*

My closest example so far is:

```
grep -Eo "X(.*?)\."  inputfile
```

But that is too greedy (even though I think I used `.*?` properly.

Can someone help guide me to a proper regex?

Comment: why grep ? This sounds like a job for cut -d '.' -f1 | cut -d '[' -f2, to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using `.*` properly but as you noticed it is greedily eating up as many characters as it can in your match because `.` matches any character. You could do:

```
grep -Eo "X([^.]*?)\." inputFile
```

This matches an X followed by any length sequence of any non dot (`[^.]*`) up to some character (`?`) and a dot (`\.`). You say you are interested in everything between the first X and the first . though, so you could simplify this further:

```
grep -Eo "X[^.]*\." inputFile
```

Comment: That makes some sense.   If I know what follows `X` will only be digits, does this expression work?  "X[0-9]+\."    (I'll try all this when I get to the office tomorrow)

Comment: yes, that would also work. Generally the more restrictive your match the better. Just as an aside I hadn't seen the `-o` switch used with grep before (learn something every day!). Usually I'd use sed for something like this. In sed would have looked like this: `sed -E 's/^.*(X[^.]*\.).*$/\1/' inputFile`.

Comment: Thanks.  Any particular reason for the preference of `sed -E` over `grep -Eo`?

Comment: Habit, honestly. That said, you can accomplish more with sed than grep. It searches/replaces for single lines as well across multiple lines of your input. Suppose you wanted to filter all of the 'foobar' patterns in a file and then transpose foo with bar (barfoo). You could do that with sed, but not grep: `sed -E 's/(foo)(bar)/\2\1/' inputFile`

Comment: It seems there is an important difference in how they operate:  sed allows everything through, processing only what matches.  grep blocks everything, allowing through only what matches.

Comment: Not really...Grep will filter your input with regular expressions: either everything matching or everything matching a pattern (-v option, very handy). Sed will edit your input with regular expressions - it can do what grep can and more. But its also more complicated (ie, to make it do the standard `grep foo inputFile` you'd type `sed -n '/foo/ p' inputFile`). Moral of the story: use the simpler tool for the simpler problem!